# PHP page not receiving all POST data from iOS app

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, json, post

I am posting data from an iOS application to a PHP page. It is receiving this data, however, it does not seem to be receiving all of the post data, just about half of it. The data I am sending is a serialized image so it is quite large.

I am using the following code to post the data from the app:

```
NSError *error;
NSData *data =[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:0 error:&error];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:link];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)data.length] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody:data];

NSURLResponse *response = nil;
error = nil;

NSData *result = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

I am then using the following PHP code to get this post data.

```
$handle = fopen('php://input','r');
$jsonInput = fgets($handle);

$decoded = json_decode($jsonInput,true);
```

This seems to work fine and works in other areas of my project, but no other areas are posting such large data.

I have also tried creating a HTML form and posting this data via this form to see if there was some kind of size limit on the post data. However, when I post the data through the html form it works fine, posting all of it.

Could this issue be to do with the fopen/fgets commands and some kind of size limit on the data they can retrieve?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm assuming you've base64 encoded the image bytes? I'd suggest scrapping the JSON approach altogether and sending the HTTP request with the appropriate MIME type for your image type (e.g., "image/png") and the raw image bytes--or, if you are sending other parameters, send a "multipart/form-data" request.

Comment: Would either of these approaches have less data being transmitted? If not, could you suggest how I can achieve what you describe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was posting all the data, just the datatype 'blob' in my database was not large enough to hold the value.

Changed this to 'longblob' and it now works fine.